# Calculate position of object rotating around an axis

Tags: trigonometry, 3d, rotations

I have the value `θ` with range `[0, 360]` of the object rotating about the y-axis pictured below. Given a certain radius `r` I want to calculate the position `p` of the object on the `x, z` plane.

[image]

EDIT: Yes, I know I can use sine and cosine to figure out the problem if the axis was on the same orientation as the plane I want to find the position in, but I'm not sure how to do it if the axis is projecting outwards.

EDIT 2: I'm hella dumb, sorry. I just realized the angle between `r` and `x` is `θ` and I can just use sine and cosine. It's been a long day.

Comment: Do you know about sine and cosine?

Comment: http://mathcentral.uregina.ca/QQ/database/QQ.09.10/h/shelby2.1.gif

Answer (score 1):

$\begin{bmatrix}
x'\\
y'\\
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
cos(\theta) & sin(\theta)\\
-sin(\theta) & cos(\theta)\\
\end{bmatrix} \cdot \begin{bmatrix}
x\\
y\\
\end{bmatrix}$

Multiplying a vector with a rotationmatrix will give you the position after a rotation with an angle $\theta$.